# I have a DNS error: "Error resolving “10.20.205.124 ”: Name or service not known "

Tags: networking, apt, gnome, dns, flatpak

> I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed, and I wanted to use GNOME's online
> account manager but I have received this weird message: [image: the error message]
>
> After a bit of research ,I figured out it may have something to do
> with DNS /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname files:-

```
#etc/hosts file's content
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       VM
127.0.0.1       felix

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters


# This server name is used by several labs, including 
# XSS, CSRF, SQL injection, Shellshock, Hash length extension labs
10.9.0.5        www.seed-server.com

# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1       kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

etc/host file

```
   felix
```

But that IP "10.20.205.124 " aren't  in these files .and even strangely I get the same errors when attempting to install any software through the  Ubuntu Software app
[image]

The same error came on an seemingly unrelated place,that it  when I attempted to install flatpak with these  2 commands:

```
sudo apt install flatpak
```

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
error: Can't load uri https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo: Error resolving “10.20.205.124 ”: Name or service not known
```

***Amazingly this error disappears  when I give it sudo privleges!***

Any guess as to what or where the problem could be?

Edit #1 here is my proxy settings:

```
$ echo $http_proxy
http://10.20.205.124 :8080/
```

[image: Network proxy setting]

Comment: Look at “Error resolving '“10.20.205.124 ”'” there is a space at the end of the string. This space transforms an IP Address into a DNS name - which cannot be resolved. It is unclear to me where this “IP-Address” is coming from. Is it configured somewhere ?

Comment: Please do not post PICTURES of text. Include the text in the body of the question.

Comment: Yep I did feel like that extra space is a culprit,but coudn't figure out where it was configured .I did ran a grep -r '10.20.205.124' in the /etc folder but it returned no results So I'm not sure where it is configured.

Comment: What network are you on? Does `echo $http_proxy` give any results?

Comment: The Question of vidarlo is very useful - do you use the IP 10.20.205.124 locally and if so, in which function?

Comment: hey when I ran echo $http_proxy The output appered as  http://10.20.205.124 .and  the problem remains wether I'm on a regular home network or an University netwrok

Comment: and @dummyuser no I don't use that speicific I.P. for any specific purpose .It may be because of my proxy setting .<check out the edit I made in my question>